# Hanafi doing sajda and iftirash sitting position and imamat

Tags: salat, hanafi

1] I have difficulties to do sajda the proper way: first go down on the knees, than place hands and than head with nose and forehead forced to the ground.
When I go down for sajda I use my hands to lean on and than place knees and the rest.

**Question**: how can I train to do sajda in the proper way?

2] Other situation: Sitting in ifirash position between 2 rakaat and after last rakaat.

I have difficulty bending my left foot and to sit on it (muscles are stiff) and my right foot facing the front.

**Question**: How can I train to manage this position?

3] With the situation described above, is it allowed to do imamat?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. In the Maliki school of fiqh performing sujud with the hands on the ground before the knees reach it is recommended. So on the whole this is not false by default. Further it is not recommended to ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: How about in Hanfi fiqh?

Comment: @user2494430 is indeed Hanafi Fiqh.